# How to call one Fragment Method from another Fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application I want **2 `fragments`** in a  `Activity`. and for showing these 2 `fragments` I use `ViewPager`.

In **`Fragment` two** I have one method, and I want call this method from **`Fragment` one**!

My method in Fragment two :

```
public void getComments() {

    JsonObject requestBean = new JsonObject();
    requestBean.addProperty("entityType", 4);
    requestBean.addProperty("reviewType", 5);
    requestBean.addProperty("reviewUserType", 2);
    requestBean.addProperty("entityID", serialID);
    requestBean.addProperty("celebrityId", 0);
    requestBean.addProperty("pageIndex", 1);
    requestBean.addProperty("pageSize", 10);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CommentResponse> call = api.getComments(token, requestBean);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CommentResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CommentResponse> call, Response<CommentResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                    reviewSerialFrag_NoComment.setText("");
                } else {
                    reviewSerialFrag_NoComment.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.noReviews));
                }
                commentModel.clear();
                commentModel.addAll(response.body().getData());
                commentsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentsListAdapter);

                reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsUserTypeText.setText(userTypeStr);
                reviewSerialFrag_newsCommentsReviewTypeText.setText(reviewTypeStr);

                reviewSerialFrag_Progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CommentResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            reviewSerialFrag_Progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

**And call this method with below codes from Fragment one :**

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<SendCommentResponse> call = api.getSendComment(token, sendData);

showView(loadProgress);
goneView(sendBtn);

call.enqueue(new Callback<SendCommentResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SendCommentResponse> call, Response<SendCommentResponse> response) {
        if (response.body().getData()) {

            Alerter.create(getActivity())
                    .setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.successSendComment))
                    .setDuration(2000)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tick_new)
                    .setBackgroundColorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
                    .enableSwipeToDismiss()
                    .enableProgress(true)
                    .setOnShowListener(new OnShowAlertListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onShow() {
                            watchlistDialog.dismiss();
                            goneView(loadProgress);
                            showView(sendBtn);
                        }
                    })
                    .setOnHideListener(new OnHideAlertListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onHide() {
                            infoEpisodeFrag_addWatchList.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_eye_white));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_addWatchList.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#1da8b9")));

                            getData();
                            new EpisodeDetail_ReviewFrag().getComments();
                        }
                    })
                    .setProgressColorRes(R.color.whiteMe)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SendCommentResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

**But show me this error in LogCat :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.app, PID: 11978
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.app.Fragments.EpisodeDetailFrags.EpisodeDetail_ReviewFrag$6.onResponse(EpisodeDetail_ReviewFrag.java:305)
                                                                             at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Show me error for this line in **`Fragment` two** :

```
reviewSerialFrag_NoComment.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.noReviews));
```

How can I fix it? Please help me

Comment: If you are using a viewpager, I assume there is only one fragment visible at a time. So why would you want to call a method on another fragment which is not visible to the user? (The implementation problem is that you don't have any guarantee that there is a fragment instance to execute the method)

Comment: @Juan. can you send to me code? I am amateur. please

Comment: You need to rethink the app, it is not a question of a 2 lines change. Put the core functionality in the activity, and have the fragments pull from there the info they need to show on screen. Use fragment.getActivity() to get an instance of the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really a bad idea to use Fragments like regular classes. Even when you want to pass simple data around you'd use and instance or use the bundle.

If your method does not rely on the fragment itself, create a separate utility class that both fragments share. Just pass it a context so it can resolve some of the variables in it.

Separate the UI manipulation in a separate class within your fragments. Create a listener to this utility class and change the visual state in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `getResources()` method. Just `getString(R.string.noReviews)` works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of fragment

```
ExampleFrag frag=(ExampleFrag)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

Then call any method

```
 frag.myMethod();
```